# Fill list in flutter from other page

Tags: flutter, dart

On fetchDept.dart I have:

```
Future<List<Dept>> fetchDept() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.https('someurl.com', 'dept'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List<Dept> dept = (json.decode(response.body)["items"]  as List)
        .map((data) => Dept.fromJson(data))
        .toList();
    return dept;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Error');
  }
}
```

How on other dart page load data from fetchDept.dart (fetchDept) to deptList

Details.dart page:

```
import 'package:services/fetchDept.dart';

class DropListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DropListPageState createState() => _DropListPageState();
}

class _DropListPageState extends State<DropListPage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchDept();
    super.initState();
  }

  List deptList;
  String _myDept;

  //deptList  ==> Set here data from  fetchDept()
```

On Details.dart page I need to populate Dropdown list.

Comment: Please put a little mroe explanation of what you are trying to accomplish. What you have tried, what errors you are facing and more. Please post all code neccesarry if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the Details page, you could store your data into a List and use it to build your widgets, like this:

```
import 'package:services/fetchDept.dart';

class DropListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DropListPageState createState() => _DropListPageState();
}

class _DropListPageState extends State<DropListPage> {
  List deptList=[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    asyncMethod();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> asyncMethod() async{
    List result = await fetchDept();
    setState((){
      deptList=result;
    });
  }

  String _myDept;

  //with the help of deptList you could build your widgets
```

Comment: Tnx for help, but get error: https://ibb.co/TLzkfRR

Comment: @babayaro please check now!